# Почему бы всегда не использовать display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css, display, inline-block

Отличия inline и inline-block в том, что inline-block можно задавать размеры и у него работает margin сверху и снизу. Почему бы всегда не использовать inline-block?

Comment: Потому что inline-block имеет геометрию прямоугольника (блока), а inline не имеет определённой геометрии и подстраивавтся под содержимое текущей строки. Это разные инструменты для разных задач

Comment: @andreymal, содержимое строки может быть не прямоугольным?

Comment: @Grundy это может быть несколько прямоугольников (несколько строк)

Comment: `inline` больше для текстовой разметки подходит. А `inline-block` уже для блочной верстки.

Comment: @andreymal а можете привести пример?